# d3 scaleBand not returning maximum range for last element in domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a scaleBand to scale the x axis of a chart. The scale will not return the maximum range for any given domain.

The example below shows a set of 4 elements in the domain, and the co-domain of the first and last element in the scale's domain.

**Expected co-domains:** 0, rangeMax * 1/3, rangeMax * 2/3, rangeMax * 3/3

**Actual co-domains:** 0, rangeMax * 1/4, rangeMax * 2/4, rangeMax * 3/4

How can I get the scale to return the former set of co-domains?

[image: scale incorrect return value]

Answer (score 0):

I was using d3.scaleBand, when what I wanted was d3.scalePoint.

Woops